# Common list among web role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have 2 web roles. Each maintains a Concurrent Dictionary which it updates. Is there a way to make sure that changes made by one is visible to others.

Or in other words, for N number of web role instances there should be only 1 copy of data (Collection or Object not DB Table).

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of a web role is a separate VM. So... whatever technique you'd use between two computers would be viable with two VMs.

You mentioned no databases, so that rules out quite a bit. You simply cannot share collections or objects because, again, you're talking about synchronization across two completely separate VMs.

Note that Cloud Services have a Cache Role as well, which you can consider for sharing content between your instances (and this is certainly not the ultimate answer; I'm simply pointing out what Cloud Services provide out-of-the-box).